# JsPDF HTML2Canvas | Genera el PDF desproporcionado, ligeramente aplastado verticalemente respecto a la web

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

Genera el archivo PDF sin problema, pero lo crea de manera ligeramente desproporcionada (verticalmente ligeramente aplastado). ¿Cómo se puede corregir para que sea de proporción exacta o más fiel? Gracias de antemano.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
  function genPDF() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("testDiv"),{
            onrendered: (canvas)=>{
                var pdf = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                
                var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

            
var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
                
doc.addImage(pdf, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Creo que el problema viene de que por un lado tienes un tamaño para el documento (A4), que tiene una proporción dada, y por otro lado tienes una imagen que tiene otras proporciones. Intenta que (`width/height === imageWidth/imageHeight)`

Comment: Disculpa, ¿de qué manera se coloca ese código? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que quieres meter en un documento A4 (210 x 297 mm) una imagen que tiene un tamaño o proporción distintas. Para solucionarlo creo que bastaría con que usaras el tamaño de la imagen y no el del PDF al añadirla:

Creas un elemento img:

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Compruebas el tamaño de la imagen resultante y usas ese tamaño:

```
const iWidth = image.naturalWidth;
const iHeight = image.naturalHeight;
doc.addImage(pdf, 'JPEG', 0, 0, iWidth, iHeights);
doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Si la imagen la quieres ajustar al tamaño del documento, has de reducir/aumentar la altura y el ancho en la misma proporción.